# Ajax url to action not working + Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I want to make an ajax call with jquery autocomplete like this:

```
$("#register_player_team").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{path('volley_scout_getteams_data')}}",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In my routing.yml I have the following route defined:

```
volley_scout_getteams_data:
pattern:  /team/getteams
defaults: { _controller: VolleyScoutBundle:Team:getteams }
```

And in my TeamController I have an action called getteamsAction():

```
public function getteamsAction()
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // Get teams from database
    $teams = $entityManager->getRepository('VolleyScoutBundle:Teams')->findAll();

    foreach($teams as $team){
        var_dump($team);
    }

    die();
}
```

(The dump and die() is just for testing, I want to check if he can find the link).
But when I want to make the ajax call I always get the following error:

```
http://localhost:8080/volleyscout/web/app_dev.php/user/%7B%7Bpath('volley_s…)%7D%7D?callback=jQuery110207641139030456543_1389372448462&_=1389372448463 404 (Not Found)
```

For some reason he can't find the action ... Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong? And when I try the link like this: `web/app_dev.php/team/getteams` I get a dump of the teams ..

**UPDATE:**
My javascript links are defined in base view (twig) like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '@VolleyScoutBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
        '@VolleyScoutBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
    %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the ajax call is in my page.js:

```
(function () {
    $("#register_userType").change(function(){
        var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        if(value == 'P' || value == 'T'){
            $('.teams').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.teams').hide();
        }
    });
    $("#register_player_team").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{path('volley_scout_getteams_data')}}",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I did the following things:

- Installed the bundle
- Added the bundle to my AppKernel
- Registered the routing definition in app/config/routing.yml
- Published assets (php app/console assets:install --symlink web)

Added the 2 javascript lines to my base.html.twig like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '@VolleyScoutBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
        '@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/public/js/router.js'
        '@VolleyScoutBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        '@VolleyScoutBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js'
    %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/volleyscout/js/security.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

But now I get this errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/volleyscout/web/app_dev.php/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData 500 (Internal Server Error) register:117
Uncaught Error: The route "volley_scout_getteams_data" does not exist.
```

It's very strange. When I clear my cache, the first time it works perfectly. And when I refresh it shows the errors ...

Comment: is your javascript located within a twig template?  If it is in an external javascript file, twig syntax will not work.

Comment: My javascript is defined in my base.html.twig (I updated my begin post for more information)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following line in your javascript code

```
url: "{{path('volley_scout_getteams_data')}}",
```

won't work...

The best way is to use the <kbd>[FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd> Install <kbd>[FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)</kbd> to expose your routing in your JavaScript code. (very straight-forward)

<kbd>2</kbd> Enable your route

```
volley_scout_getteams_data:
    pattern:  /team/getteams
    defaults: { _controller: VolleyScoutBundle:Team:getteams }
    options:
        expose: true
```

<kbd>3</kbd> Adapt your js

```
var getTeamsUrl = Routing.generate('volley_scout_getteams_data');

$("#register_player_team").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: getTeamsUrl,
            //...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but afterwards I get this error .. Could you take a look at it? I think I'm missing something stupid..

Comment: This is very likely to be a bug, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058326/fosjsroutingbundle-dont-recognize-route/21059336#21059336).

Comment: Install a `stable` version of the bundle please, see: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/releases.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question/answer and almost started to install the mentioned **FOSJsRoutingBundle** mentioned by @Mick in the answer. As I had the exact same problem in my Ajax Request I couldn't get the URL. But now I don't see the need to get the FOSJsRoutingBundle..

What is an input field without a `<form>` tag? Or even better: why is my `<input>` field not in a `<form>`? It is absolutely valid HTML to have `<input>` fields outside a form tag, but it actually makes no sense.

Anyway, it makes sense to have `<form>` arround the `<input>` so also if the javascript shouldn't work, why so ever, it would sent the request to the right place and load the page. So now if you have a form arround the input just grab the URL from there...

This worked for me:

Add a `<form>`

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('volley_scout_getteams_data')}) }}
```

get the URL/path with javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
```

Answer (score 0):

remove {{ }} from your ajax url.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install any bundles. You can use DOM Location hostname property - `window.location.origin`.

First create a simple global function

```
function getRootUrl() {
    return window.location.origin;
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere, for example like this:

```
var getTeamsUrl = getRootUrl() + "/volley/scout/get-teams";

$("#register_player_team").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: getTeamsUrl,
            //...
        });
    }
});
```

**Note:** 
It works for me, but there may be circumstances under which this solution may cause some problems.