# FOSJsRoutingBundle dont recognize route

Tags: javascript, symfony, url-routing

I'm trying use `FOSJsRoutingBundle` to generate urls from symfony routes.
I follow the [doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#usage).

I include the files into my `base.html.twig`:

```
{% block scripting %}
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>        
...
{% endblock %}
```

And don't get inclusion error. But the try to generate an url fails:

```
console.log(Routing.generate('usuarios_crear'));
```

> GET
>   http://appsmanantiales.local/web/app_dev.php/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData
>   500 (Internal Server Error) listar:131 Uncaught Error: The route
>   "usuarios_crear" does not exist. router.js:9

In my `routing.yml` I have:

```
usuarios_crear:
    pattern: /AbmUsuarios/crear
    defaults: { _controller: AbmBundle:Usuario:crear }
    options:
        expose: true
```

And the route is in `php app/console fos:js-routing:debug` list:

> usuarios_crear        ANY    ANY    ANY  /AbmUsuarios/crear

Any ideas?

Comment: Obvious, but easily missed, question but have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having the same problem :/

Comment: @nielsv try to install the stable version, not the master-dev.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is great.

I suggest that you open an issue [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues), this is very likely to be a bug as [you're not the only one to have that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049886/ajax-url-to-action-not-working-symfony2/21050269#21050269).

Comment: Thank i think about this.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easier than you think. 
Visit the page generated here: `{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}` it should have json-encoded list of your exposed routes. If your route is there you're good.

How check when you execute `console.log(Routing.generate('usuarios_crear'));`
The document should be ready before you try that. So make sure it is (i.e. `jQuery's $('document').ready()`).

Comment: Is the same result. I test on Document.ready, plugins, JS plain.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [Github issues](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues), found [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/121) where the author suggest not use the dev-master version.
I do a downgrade to "@stable", and works (for now).
The composer.json line may be:

> "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "@stable"

For more detail: [The full install guide.](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation)

Answer (score 0):

Don't require `dev-master` in a composer.json file, never ever, ever! It is a bad practice.

Rely on stable releases please: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/releases

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, and the solution was include the `^/js/*` route to access anonymously in your security configuration.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this code
Suppose you have the an `onclick` function that receives an `id` when clicked so your js code will something like this

```
function show(id)
{

    var url = '{{ path('usuarios_crear',{ id: 'id' }, {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}';
    url = url.replace("id", id);
    window.location.href = url;

}
```